# I am trying to put this glitched image in my website, I put the CSS code and HTML in but it still does not work

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to use code from codepen. Is it right that all I have to do is copy the CSS and HTML? Also, do I have to add in the SCSS? Thanks!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbzawL

HTML

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>

<div class="glitch" data-text="GLITCH">GLITCH</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the codepen to work using the compiled CSS pasted into the style section of the html page. The HTML worked just fine in the body section of the page.

Comment: doh. I missed the compiled css @rreg101 this is the right answer

Answer (score 5):

Well its correct all you need is what's on codepen.

However that isn't CSS its SCSS (sass) so you would need to compile that code to generate CSS that you could then use on your website. That is also using compass that you would need to install too. You install all of this using ruby.

[Heres a helpful link that will get you set up with sass & compass](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass)